# How to Run as Administrator a VirtualPC VM?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-virtual-pc

To get advanced NAT* functionality in a VM I want to run VirtualPC as Administrator.

The regular right click and select "Run as Administrator" does not work (in Task Manager I see it is not running with elevated privileges, also only TCP connections work in the VM, no ping or other protocols)

So how to run it with elevated privileges?
Turning UAC off is not an option.

I use Windows 7 64 bit Enterprise with all updates (SP1 and beyond).

* - anything beyond TCP, see blog [Virtual PC, Shared Networking and the problems with Ping](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/virtual_pc_guy/2007/04/27/virtual-pc-shared-networking-and-the-problems-with-ping/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you (I) go:

- Start *Command Prompt* (cmd.exe) as Administrator
- `cd where\the\VMC\files\are`
- `vpc.exe`
- `myvirtual1.vmc`

(Pre)conditions:

- vpc.exe is not running (it hosts the running virtual machines, so it means no virtual machines running). Otherwise the existing vpc.exe (that runs with normal privileges) will be (re)used.
- do the last command quickly, as vpc.exe will exit after a few seconds if no VMs are started, and a regular privileged vpc.exe will be started instead

Or to do it from a BAT script file, put this into a file and name it like *AdminVPC.bat* :

```
cd /d C:\VMs\VirtualPC
powershell Start-Process vpc.exe -Verb RunAs
start "" "My virtual PC.vmc"
rem the second line need no admin privileges, the actual work is done by VPC.exe
rem _start_ is needed otherwise the CMD window waits until the VM is closed
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you mentioned Windows 7. This means you are using Windows Virtual PC, the component. It cannot be run as Administrator because it is now integrated into Windows Shell.

You need to downgrade to Microsoft Virtual PC 2007.

> Or... move on to an actual virtualization app that [doesn't suck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Virtual_PC#Removed_features).

Comment: This is wrong, see the accepted answer.